# How can I improve a loop in octave?

Tags: octave

I have this code:

```
N1 = 21;   N2 = 21;   nv = N1*N2;   L = 1.0;  
delta = L / (N1-1);   sigma = 1.0;   

% Assembly mass and stiffness matrizes
[K M] = MatMembrane(N1,N2,sigma,delta);

% Compute generalized eigenvalues and eigevectors
[V D] = eig(K,M);

% Auxiliary matrizes
zeronv = zeros(nv);  idennv = eye(nv);  invM = diag(1./diag(M));
A = [zeronv, idennv; -invM*K, zeronv];
A = sparse(A);   % Convert to sparse format

% Program your initial condition
iniw = V(:,1);   % for example
iniv = zeros(nv,1);

% Loop over time steps
ti = 0;   tf = 10.0;   pt = 1000;  t = linspace(ti,tf,pt);
lambda = -1;   n = 1;
  % Initial condition
z(:,1) = [iniw ; iniv];

t(1) = ti;  alpha = 0.5;   h = 5e-1;   

while t(n) <= tf - h  
   z(:,n+1) = ((eye(882) + (h*(1.0 - alpha)).*A)/(eye(882) + (h*alpha).*A))*z(:,n);
   z = sparse(z);   
   t(n+1) = t(n) + h;
   n = n + 1;
end
```

In this while loop the octave spend a lot of time to get the matrix "z". Is it possible to improve this loop?
Before this loop, it is fast.

Comment: Did you preallocate `Z`? If not, that's going to take a whole lot of time. Here 's the [MATLAB documentation page](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html) on what preallocation is and why it's important; it's the same for Octave.

Comment: I have the z(:,1) = [iniw ; iniv] before the loop.

Comment: Please [edit] the post to contain a [mcve], i.e. **complete** code that **we** can run. So provide sample input (preferably in `rand()` mode or so, in order to avoid posting 20,000 characters of your data), and all of the relevant code. Otherwise we're just stabbing in the dark.

Comment: Your issue is that you are making a dense matrix in every iteration, and then making it sparse! Its much much faster if you build sparse matrices from indices and values, and perhaps overwrite the previous ones. This simple code will be equally memory consuming/effcient, but much faster if you just remove the `z=sparse(z)` line

Comment: Interesting fact. Thank you